# Ansible Get dict value from key

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have two files, one with 2 dict and another playbook that use those dict.

Vars file:

`data: {path: ~/prod/iac/playbook/test.conf, conf: test2}
vagrant: {path: ~/prod/iac/playbook/test.conf/test2.conf, conf: test4}`

and the playbook:

`---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Include var for nginx config
      include_vars:
        file: ~/prod/iac/playbook/vars.yml
        name: conf_vars
    - name: overide doc configuration
      shell: echo  "{{ item[path] }}" > test.conf
      with_items: " {{ conf_vars }}"`

My vars is correctly loaded but i can't get the dict value... 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conf_vars` is a dictionary, `with_items` is to be used with lists.

You may want to use `with_dict`:

```
- name: overide doc configuration
  shell: echo  "{{ item.value[path] }}" > test.conf
  with_dict: "{{ conf_vars }}"
```